# How to format data before displaying it on ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I've just discovered [ag-grid](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular). I'm using it on angular2+ and loading data from api. One of fields is date, but its in ISO format. I've been trying to format it, is there any way to do it, is it possible to add pipe or some other way? Usually i do it like this {{ someISODate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}}. Do i really have to format it manually in component before displaying it? Also I was wondering if its possible to add two fields under one column. Why? Well i have column author, and in data that im getting from api i have author.firstname and author.lastname, and now I wanna display both fields in same column. Any hints or examples are more than welcomed.

```
columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Datum kreiranja', field: 'createdAt' }, //<-- wanna format it
    {headerName: 'Vrsta predmeta', field: 'type.name' },
    {headerName: 'Opis', field: 'description'},
    {headerName: 'Kontakt', field: 'client.name'},
    {headerName: 'Autor', field: 'author.firstname'}, //<-- wanna display author.lastname in same cell
    {headerName: 'Status', field: 'status.name'}
];
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do this by using `cellRenderer` ***(or `valueFormatter` as pointed in the UPDATE)*** and `moment` library.

```
 {
      headerName: 'Datuk kreiranja', field: 'createdAt',
      cellRenderer: (data) => {
          return moment(data.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')
      }
 }
```

If you don't want to use `moment`, then below is how you can do it.

```
cellRenderer: (data) => {
     return data.value ? (new Date(data.value)).toLocaleDateString() : '';
}
```

For `Author` field as well,

```
cellRenderer: (data) => {
     return data.author.firstname + ' ' + data.author.lastname;
}
```

Reference: ***[ag-grid: Cell Rendering](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/)***

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @Mariusz, using `valueFormatter` makes more sense in this  scenario. As per documentation, [Value Formatter vs Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-formatters/#value-formatter-vs-cell-renderer)

> value formatter's are for text formatting and cell renderer's are for
> when you want to include HTML markup and potentially functionality to
> the cell. So for example, if you want to put punctuation into a value,
> use a value formatter, but if you want to put buttons or HTML links
> use a cell renderer.

Comment: are you familiar with hidding column thats grouped by? for eg. all columns are shown, i click group by author -> author col gets hidden in rows but its shown on a group

Comment: import * as moment from 'moment'; you have to add this to get that working. Basic stuff, thought it will be helpful for some one

Comment: @Paritosh when I try to convert UTC to DD MMM YYY using moment I always get the todays value. any idea how to fix this please

Comment: @RagavanRajan - not getting you. could you reproduce your issue on jsbin or plunk? post as a separate question if possible

Comment: Data is data of the node, you need to call data.data.createdAt

Comment: The formatter, in that case, is a lot better approach - please look at [ValueFormatter vs CellRenderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-formatters/#value-formatter-vs-cell-renderer)

Comment: small correction , in the moment example it should be data.value instead of data.createdAt return moment(data.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')

Answer (score 12):

You can use `valueFormatter`

```
{headerName: 'Datuk kreiranja', field: 'createdAt', valueFormatter: this.dateFormatter},
```

Create a small function:

```
dateFormatter(params) {
  return moment(params.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the formatter, in that case, is a lot better approach - please look at [ValueFormatter vs CellRenderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-formatters/#value-formatter-vs-cell-renderer)

Answer (score 4):

First of all thanks to Paritosh. 
The issue I was facing is the date field I was receiving from API is on the below format

> "endDateUTC":"2020-04-29T12:00:00",

I have followed Paritosh solution using cellrenderer along with moment library but the value was **always formatted to today's** date for some reason.

The below solution is using **valueFormatter with moment library**.

This is for Angular2+ version. The job is really simple

**In your .ts file:**

```
    import * as moment from 'moment';

{
    headerName: 'End Date',
    field: 'endDateUTC',
    minWidth: 80,
    maxWidth: 100,
    valueFormatter: function (params) {
        return moment(params.value).format('D MMM YYYY');
    },
},
```

And the output you will get is:

End date: 
29 APR 2020

Please feel free to change the date format you need.

Hope this will be helpful to some one.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to expand on Vishwajeet's excellent answer from April 2019.  Here's how I would use his code, and which `import` commands would be required:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';

    constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string)
    {
    }

    columnDefs = [
        { headerName: 'Last name', field: 'lastName' },
        { headerName: 'First name', field: 'firstName' },
        { headerName: 'DOB', field: 'dob', cellRenderer: (data) => { return formatDate(data.value, 'd MMM yyyy HH:mm', this.locale); }},
        { headerName: 'Policy start', field: 'policyStartDate', cellRenderer: (data) => { return formatDate(data.value, 'd MMM yyyy HH:mm', this.locale); } },
        { headerName: 'Policy end', field: 'policyEndDate', cellRenderer: (data) => { return formatDate(data.value, 'd MMM yyyy HH:mm', this.locale); } }
    ]
```

And your `agGrid` would contain something like this:

```
  <ag-grid-angular 
      class="ag-theme-material" 
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

This works really nicely, but I decided to move the date formatting into it's own cell renderer for a few reasons:

1. The code above will display *null* values as "`1 Jan 1970 01:00`"
2. You would need to repeat this code, plus the imports and @Inject, into any control which uses it.
3. It repeats the logic each time, so if you wanted to change the date format throughout your application, it's harder to do.  Also, if a future version of Angular broke that date formatting, you'd need to apply a fix for each occurrence.

So, let's move it into it's own cell renderer.

My *DateTimeRenderer.ts* file looks like this:

```
import { Component, LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'datetime-cell',
    template: `<span>{{ formatTheDate(params.value) }}</span>`
})
export class DateTimeRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

    public params: ICellRendererParams; 

    constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string) { }

    agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    formatTheDate(dateValue) {
        //  Convert a date like "2020-01-16T13:50:06.26" into a readable format
        if (dateValue == null)
            return "";
        return formatDate(dateValue, 'd MMM yyyy HH:mm', this.locale);
    }

    public onChange(event) {
        this.params.data[this.params.colDef.field] = event.currentTarget.checked;
    }

    refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In my *app.module.ts* file, I need to import this Component:

```
import { DateTimeRenderer } from './cellRenderers/DateTimeRenderer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DateTimeRenderer
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([DateTimeRenderer])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

And now, back in my Component which uses the agGrid, I can remove `LOCALE_ID, Inject` from this line:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

..remove it from our constructor...

```
constructor()
{
}
```

..import our new renderer...

```
import { DateTimeRenderer } from './cellRenderers/DateTimeRenderer';
```

..and change the columnDefs to use the new renderer:

```
columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Last name', field: 'lastName' },
    { headerName: 'First name', field: 'firstName' },
    { headerName: 'DOB', field: 'dob', cellRenderer: 'dateTimeRenderer' },
    { headerName: 'Policy start', field: 'policyStartDate', cellRenderer: 'dateTimeRenderer' },
    { headerName: 'Policy end', field: 'policyEndDate', cellRenderer: 'dateTimeRenderer' }
]
frameworkComponents = {
    dateTimeRenderer: DateTimeRenderer
}
```

And I just need to make sure my agGrid knows about this new frameworkComponents section:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
      class="ag-theme-material" 
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
      [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

And that's it.

Again, the nice thing about this is I can use this date formatter anywhere throughout my code, and all the logic is in one place.

It's just shocking that, in 2020, we actually *need* to write our own date formatting function for an up-to-date grid like agGrid...  this really should've been included in the agGrid libraries.

Answer (score 2):

For Angular, if you want to do this without moment.js you can try something like below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xyz'
})
export class xyzComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string ) {
  }

  columnDefs = [

    {headerName: 'Submitted Date', field: 'lastSubmittedDate', cellRenderer: (data) => {
      return  formatDate(data.value, 'dd MMM yyyy', this.locale);
     }];

}
```

This component is using format date of angular/common

Comment: Excellent code... but shocking that agGrid insists that we need such complexity, just to display a date as a nicely formatted string.   This should come out of the box.

Comment: Just to say, I'm going to post an answer, based on this solution, which moves the logic into it's own renderer.  The advantage is that it'll prevent the need to repeat this "formatDate" code, and also easily cope with datetimes of null, which this code will show as 01-01-1970.   (I hope that's okay...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        {
            headerName: 'Order Date',
            field: 'OrderDate',
            valueFormatter: function (params) {
               var nowDate = new Date(parseInt(params.value.substr(6)));
               return nowDate.format("yyyy-mm-dd");
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

**(Working & Optimized solution for date formatting is here!)**

Tested on Angular 8 with dynamic data where date is coming like 2019-11-16T04:00:00.000Z.
In Ag-grid if you use valueFormatter, then no need of including "field:'Order Date'".

Also following Ragavan Rajan's answer. So you need to install moment.js in your angular CLI.

Working code and installation is below:

```
//Install moment.js in angular 8 cli.(no need of --save in latest versions
  npm install moment

//In your component.ts
  import * as moment from 'moment';

//Inside your colDef of ag-grid
  {
    headerName: "Effective Date",
    field: "effectiveDate",
    valueFormatter: function (params){
       return moment (params.value).format ('DD MMM, YYYY');
 }

/*
* This will display formatted date in ag-grid like 16 Nov, 2019.
* field name's value is from server side.(column name).
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have two subfields like "Start Date" and "End Date" then you are supposed to do like this:

```
{
    headerName: "Date Range",
    children: [
      { 
        field: 'StartDate', 
        cellRenderer: (data) => {
          return data ? (new Date(data.value)).toLocaleDateString() : '';
        } 
      },
      {
        field: 'EndDate', 
        cellRenderer: (data) => {
          return data ? (new Date(data.value)).toLocaleDateString() : '';
        } 
      }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AdapTable then you can do it via their Format Column function which can be applied either at design-time or run-time.  And there you can choose pretty much any DateTime format that you want.
https://demo.adaptabletools.com/style/aggridformatcolumndemo

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using Angular 10, And I achieved the date formatting by using cellRenderer and DatePipe

```
  {
    field: "fieldName",
    cellRenderer: (res) => {
        const datepipe : DatePipe = new DatePipe("en-US");            
        var x = datepipe.transform(res.data.fieldName.split('T')[0],"yyyy-MM-dd");
        return x;
    }
  },
```

Split('T') is used because when you call the Api, date comes in this format
"2021-07-31T00:00:00.000Z".